# Chequear si el valor existe en la db y, si no existe, ejecutar update

Tags: php, mysql, telegram

Lo que necesito es que se verifique si en columna `pidio` de la tabla `faucet` de la base de datos está el valor `true` o `false` (el valor por defecto es `false`). Si está en `false`, hacer algo; si está en `true`, no hacer nada.

Éste es parte de mi código:

```
case "/claim":
    $check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM faucet WHERE telegramid = '$chatId'");
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
        $pidio = $row1['pidio'];
        $wallet = $row1['wallet'];
    }
    if ($pidio == 'true'){ 
        $slq2="UPDATE faucet SET pidio = true WHERE telegramid = $chatId";
        mysql_query($con,$sql2);
        sendMessage($chatId, "vuelve en 12 horas :P");
    } else { 
        $sql1="UPDATE faucet SET claims = claims + 1 WHERE telegramid = $chatId";
        $slq2="UPDATE faucet SET pidio = true WHERE telegramid = $chatId";
        mysql_query($con,$sql1);
        mysql_query($con,$sql2);
        $return2  = $shellObj->exeCmd($daemon.' getbalance '.$wallet);
        $return1  = $shellObj->exeCmd($daemon.' sendfrom '.$faucetd.' '.$wallet.' '.$faucet);
        $suma = $return1 + $return2; 
        sendMessage($chatId, "te hemos regalado ".$faucet);
        sendMessage($chatId, "el pago a sido enviado \ntu balance es ".$return2."\n se te abonaran ".$faucet."\n saldo final ".$suma);
    }
```

Comment: Pues en tu codigo ya estas haciendo esa validacion con tu `if ($pidio == 'true')`, o te sale algun error?

Comment: no es que me de un error es que no se hace ninguna actualizacion antes lo tenia con 1 y con 0 y si le cambiaba ejemplo en el if true por 1 o por 0 en el bot me aparecia el mensaje vuelve en 12 horas lo cual es raro ya que no deberia pasar eso

Comment: entiendo, pues porque no intentas imprimendo `$pidio`?

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow (completa para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla). Pregunta: ¿cómo falla lo que tienes ya hecho? ¿No funciona?

Comment: Aparte, no relacionado con la pregunta: cuidado al usar sentencias concatenando cadenas. Abre la puerta a que se pueda dar ataques de inyección SQL (no sé de donde salen los valores que concatenas, pero por noma general sería mejor usar una sentencia preparada).

Comment: esas variables estan en el archivo config donde tengo la conexion a la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo que hagas debug de tu código. Estoy viéndolo y debe funcionarte. Lo que te está pasando es que nunca está entrando al if sino en el else.

Trata de ver que valor te trae la variable $pidio y te recomiendo que le quites la comillas ('') en el if 'true' ya q 'true' es diferente de 1 ponle directamente si es igual a '1' o si es igual a 1 o simplemente quitale las comillas ('') a 'true' y déjalo en true solo.

Así:
if ($pidio == true)

o así
if ($pidio == '1')

Espero te ayude

Cuéntanos.

Comment: Hola, adhiero a esta respuesta. Intenta realizando un print_r($pidio) y verificar el resultado.
Primeramente deberías revisar sí la consulta SQL esta devolviendo lo esperado y posteriormente revisar como lo esta recibiendo PHP.